# Javascript find adjacencies

Tags: javascript

I have a "class" called `Block`. It possesses three variables : `x`, `y`, and `z`, which are its three-dimensional coordinates, respectively. I am having trouble finding the number of "neighbours" to a block. That is, if `this` shares a face, edge, or vertex with `other`, it should return true. So, `block.neighbours()` returns the number of neighbours to `block`. However, it is returning `0` rather than the expected `1`. My code is shown below:

```
var blocks = [];

  function Block(x, y, z) {
    blocks.push(this);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.neighbours = function() {
      var n = 0;
      for (var block in blocks) {
        if (block == this) {
          continue;
        }
        if (Math.abs(block.x - this.x) <= 1 && Math.abs(block.y - this.y) <= 1 && Math.abs(block.z - this.z) <= 1) {
          n++;
        }
      }
      return n;
    };
  }

  var b1 = new Block(0, 0, 0);
  var b2 = new Block(0, 1, 0);
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = b1.neighbours();
```

Why is the function returning `0`? (Note: Before the javascript I have the html `<p id = "box"></p>`, and in the paragraph it shows `0`).

Comment: Could you double check your code? it seems as if n++ is never running...

Comment: I know that. Actually, that is the problem!

Comment: Also the `if (block == this)` isn't working.

Comment: @Nathan: it's sufficient as long as all entries have unique coordinates.

Comment: What you are calling a "block" seems to just be a single point.  How does a single x,y,z combo define a block?  How does your logic of all 3 coordinates being <=1 away from one another constitute a "face, edge or vertex" in common?

Comment: Rather than a single point, my grid is like so: Every coordinate is a space rather than a vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug in your code is that `for (var block in blocks) {` is not iterating as you expect -- `var block in blocks` iterates over the property names which are `0` and `1` as demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yxzobjhb/

You could fix it by doing this:

```
    for (var blockKey in blocks) {
        var block = blocks[blockKey];
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxzobjhb/2/

Another way to fix it would be to write it like this:

```
var blocks = [];

function Block(x, y, z) {
    blocks.push(this);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.neighbours = function() {
        var n = 0;
        blocks.forEach(function(block) {
            if (block != this && Math.abs(block.x - this.x) <= 1 && Math.abs(block.y - this.y) <= 1 && Math.abs(block.z - this.z) <= 1) {
                n++;
            }
        }, this);
        return n;
    };
}

var b1 = new Block(0, 0, 0);
var b2 = new Block(0, 1, 0);
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = b1.neighbours();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLxw316c/2/

Comment: I did not know that about arrays! You, my friend, are a genius!

Answer (score 0):

The `for ... in` statement returns keys, not the actual values of a map/array. You'd have to look up the block within each iteration, e.g.

```
var key, block;
for (key in blocks) {
    block = blocks[key]
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You shouldn't use `for...in` with arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)  However, if you do, it gets the property names, not the values.  You would have to do this:

```
for (var index in blocks) {
    var block = blocks[index];
```

In your existing code, `block` is `0` the first iteration and `1` the second.

However, you should use this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
    var block = blocks[i];
```